# Is there a data structure like a ListHashMap?

Tags: java, data-structures

I've been trying to find a data structure that will:

1. Let me check for duplicates in O(1) time (HashSet),
2. Preserve the order of insertion, and
3. Allow me to get a subset of that ordered list.

The closest thing I've found is a `LinkedHashSet`, but it just falls short by not implementing the `List` interface and allowing me to call `List` functions on it (like `subList`). Is there a reason why I can't find a structure like this? I'm about to implement my own version of `LinkedHashSet` but using an `ArrayList` instead (in contrast to the Linked-list-backed `LinkedHashSet`). I also found `OrderedHashSet` from the `org.antlr.misc` library, but this also falls short by not implementing that needed subList function... So I'm really puzzled at why this hasn't been needed? or I just haven't thought of the right name to search for?

EDIT: I'm not only trying to find an existing structure that can fulfill this requirement, but in the absence of one, I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't exist. Whoever can answer that can get the Accepted answer since I already knew how to implement it :)

EDIT 2: Sorry sorry, I should have been more clear on my 1st requirement, I really only need to check for duplicates really efficiently. It's late for me.

Comment: There is nothing linke ListHashMap in java, in case you want to use ArrayList as the key you can do so HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer>

Comment: No, I wanted 3 things from this data structure, I'll update the question

Comment: Then, please update the question so that we can take a look at.

Comment: It's not clear if what you want is a Map or a Set. A Map associates values wit keys. A Set is a collection, containing unique elements.

Comment: @TheLostMind: time doesn't have much to do with complexity. A HashMap *is* O(1), because whatever the number of elements already present in the map, inserting a new one or getting a value from it takes the same time.

Comment: atomicity has nothing to do with complexity. When asked what the complexity (BigO) of put() is, you have to wonder what's the relation is between N (the number of elements in the map) and the time it takes. Since the time doesn't vary at all with N (i.e. it will always take X nanoseconds, whether the map contains 1 or 1 million elements), then the operation is O(1). Whether it's 1 nanosecond or 1 second doesn't change anything to the complexity, as long as it stays 1 nanosecond (or 1 second) whatever N is. Contrast this to the time it takes to know if some value is in a List, which is O(N).

Comment: @TheLostMind HashSets are O(1) because it takes constant time to calculate the hashCode of an object. The only exception I can think of would be taking the hashCode of an collection datastructure where the hashCode can be calculated from the hashCodes of each element. In that case, yes it would be O(n) but I don't think it's a typical use case

Comment: Can you make your requirements more concrete. IIUC, for the 1st req. you want put(key, value) and get(key) in O(1). for the 2nd req. you want an iterator() which iterates over all key,value pairs in the order they had been .put(). For the 3rd req. I am not sure. How do you specify the begin and end position of the sublist. is it with keys or with indices? what complexity do you want for this?

Comment: @ItayMaman the subList would take arguments from indices, exactly like List.subList(int start, int end)

Comment: You could easily rig up a `LinkedHashSet` to return sublist views (using an iterator and counter).  It wouldn't be efficient, but you don't have an efficiency requirement for #3 that I see.

Comment: @BrDaHa thanks. please take a look at the  solution I posted. It meets your reqs., I believe.

Comment: Please see an update solution, below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what you're finding is something that provides O(1) point lookup but provides efficient range-scan (iteration).  In database area, such thing is sometimes called [clustered-index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Clustered), in which data are organized using some look-up structure such as [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or [hash index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), but the leaf-nodes or the entries of the index are sorted in some specific order (in your case it is sorted by insertion order).  Below shows an example of clustered B-tree, where @Itay Maman's solution is an example of clustered hash-index.

[image]

In Java, there is no such class natively satisfies your need, probably because of its complexity --- it is difficult (or nearly impossible) to have one such implementation that works best for all workload (such as how often you issue range scan, how often you issue point-lookup, does it allow multi-readers and multiple writers? ... etc) However, here are some possible solutions, depends on your use case.

1. If in most of the case you don't really care about item 3, then use LinkedHashMap, and use the normal iteration provided by LinkedHashMap to do item 3.
2. If you care the performance of all there items and you never issue deletions / update, then probably the easiest is to use HashMap and ArrayList together to represent your data as clustered-index.  Each insert is an insertion to HashMap + an append to ArrayList, and the value of the HashMap is the index of the ArrayList.  This gives you best read performance, but you need to address update / deletion if you have any, probably by replacing the ArrayList to a linked-list of sub-arrays.
3. In an extreme case, you do have deletions / update, want to support multi-thread access, and you even want persistency, then probably the best is to use an open-sourced embedded persist key-value store such as [RocksDB](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb) or [LevelDB](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), an embedded key-value store for fast storage like RAM or flash (it's also good for disk workload.)  While they are all implemented in C++, they do have Java bindings (eg. an introduction [page](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksJava-Basics) for RocksDB in Java.)

Of course, if you are ok with reimplementing something, then a customized LinkedHashMap might be the easiest one.  Just adding a different constructor of the iterator, which allows you to start the iteration at any particular entry located using O(1) hash.

Comment: 1: I require all 3, and 3: that's overkill

Comment: solution 2 handles all three case, but you will have hard-time dealing with updates and deletes.

Comment: 3 is actually not that overkill, as you will eventually implement subset of that :p

Comment: Well ok, sure, this #2 was what I was going to do, but since I won't be updating or deleting much (if at all) in this use case, it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering all of my questions!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

According to the update question, you only need a no-duplicates-collection (as opposed to a key-value mapping). This simplifies things, a bit. Basically, this solution uses:
- a (hash)set to determine dupness
- a simple (array)list to maintain the insertion order

On top of that there's is also a custom implementation of a list that we use for the sub-list. I had to roll out my own (and not rely on `ArrayList.subList()`) because the (sub)list returned from an `ArrayList` does not allow the array list to change its size, once it has been created. Luckily, with the help of `AbstractList` this was quite simple (just two methods to override).

```
package p1;

import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class OrderedSet {
  private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  private final Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

  /**
   * Inserts a value if it is not a dup.
   * @return true if "value" was actually inserted (not a dup).
   */
  public boolean put(String value) {
    if (values.contains(value)) 
      return false;

    values.add(value);
    list.add(value);
    return true;
  }

  public boolean contains(String string) {
    return values.contains(string);
  }

  public Iterator<String> iterator() {
    return list.iterator();
  }

  public int size() { return list.size(); }

  public List<String> subList(int begin, int end) {
    return new MyList(begin, end);
  }

  private class MyList extends AbstractList<String> {
    private final int begin;
    private final int end;

    public MyList(int begin, int end) {
      this.begin = begin;
      this.end = end;
    }

    @Override public String get(int index) {
      return list.get(begin + index);
    }

    @Override public int size() { 
      return end - begin;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a test that proves that it works (at least functionally, for time-complexity you'll have to trust me or to analyze implementation...):

```
package p1;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class OrderedSetTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    OrderedSet om = new OrderedSet();
    assertTrue(om.put("a"));
    assertEquals(1, om.size());
    assertTrue(om.put("b"));
    om.put("c");
    assertEquals(3, om.size());
    assertFalse(om.put("a"));
    assertEquals(3, om.size());
    om.put("d");
    assertEquals(4, om.size());
    om.put("d");
    assertEquals(4, om.size());
    om.put("e");
    assertEquals(5, om.size());


    assertTrue(om.contains("a"));
    assertTrue(om.contains("b"));
    assertTrue(om.contains("c"));
    assertTrue(om.contains("d"));
    assertTrue(om.contains("e"));
    assertFalse(om.contains("a_"));
    assertFalse(om.contains("b_"));
    assertFalse(om.contains("f"));

    Iterator<String> iter = om.iterator();
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertEquals("a", iter.next());
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertEquals("b", iter.next());
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertEquals("c", iter.next());
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertEquals("d", iter.next());
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertEquals("e", iter.next());
    assertFalse(iter.hasNext());

    List<String> sub = om.subList(2,  4);
    assertArrayEquals(new String[] { "c",  "d" }, sub.toArray(new String[0]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I was pretty close to this, the HashMap would be a nice touch for efficient indexOf(Object o) calls, but I think you might have the arguments the wrong way around... if that is what you're using the HashMap for?

Comment: @BrDaHa You're right. The hash-map is no longer needed. It was a leftover from earlier versions of. Answer updated. To your question, yes - if we want to support indexOf(Object) we will need a String -> Integer hash-map. Actually, such a map will make the hash-set obsolete: all the information that can be obtained from the hash-set can also be obtained from the hash-map.

Answer (score 0):

Would [java.util.TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) help?

It's not quite O(1) (referring to your list requirements, point 1) but natural ordering (point 2) and the subset operation (point 3) are supported.

Comment: I can't use natural ordering, I just want order preservation... I didn't know TreeSet allowed use of subList though, that's interesting considering it's a Set type

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible for a data structure to make those things available at the same time, they are contradictory : if you insert and access elements in O(1) time, it means that they are  randomly distributed (with hashcodes), and if you want to preserve the order, than the insertion and the access will cost you more time.
I believe that what you're looking for is a HashSet though, and not a HashMap. It depends on whether the order of the insertions is crucial for the future of your project, you can use either HashSet (fast, random access and insertion) or you can use ArrayList(slower, but keeps the order).
I don't think it's quite possible for you to create a data structure that fulfils the demands that you have.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is possible. I've seen very very close approximations. Take a look at OrderedHashSet: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.antlr/antlr/3.1.2-1/org/antlr/misc/OrderedHashSet.java

Comment: If you look at the implementation, you can see that the access and the insertion are far larger then O(1), since you are inserting in a ArrayList, so the worst possible case of insertion time is still O(n).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me realize I outlined my first requirement incorrectly